# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'browserTimingHeader' does not exist in type 'DocumentInitialProps'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, newrelic

I try to implement newrelic browser agent in Nextjs _document.js. But got type error, how do i solve this. This code is meant to inject newrelic agent to html at server side before serving to client/browser

Got error `Type '{ browserTimingHeader: any; html: string; head?: JSX.Element[]; styles?: JSX.Element | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>[] | ReactFragment; }' is not assignable to type 'DocumentInitialProps'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'browserTimingHeader' does not exist in type 'DocumentInitialProps'.ts(2322)` when

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
// pages/_document.tsx
const newrelic = require("newrelic");
import Document, {
  DocumentContext,
  DocumentInitialProps,
  Html,
  Head,
  Main,
  NextScript,
} from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext): Promise<DocumentInitialProps> {

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

    const browserTimingHeader = newrelic.getBrowserTimingHeader({
      hasToRemoveScriptWrapper: true,
    });

    return {
      ...initialProps,
      browserTimingHeader, ->> this line
    };
  }
  render() {
    ...
  }
}
export default MyDocument;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve the type error with [Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) to declare the type of the function's return value explicitly.

```js
class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext): Promise<DocumentInitialProps & { browserTimingHeader: string }> {

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

    const browserTimingHeader = newrelic.getBrowserTimingHeader({
      hasToRemoveScriptWrapper: true,
    });

    return {
      ...initialProps,
      browserTimingHeader, // now TS will not complain as we explicitly told TS there will be a key named "browserTimingHeader" and it is a string.
    };
  }
  render() {
    ...
  }
}
export default MyDocument;
```